# Distance to set

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $S$ be a non empty set in an inner product space $E$

Show that if $x\in E,z\in E$ and $Re<x-z, y-z> \le0$ for each $y\in S$ then
$d(x,S)=||x-z||$

I would like a clue on how to approach this. I thought about using the fact that the real of the the conjugate of this inner product is the same as the real of of the inner product and then use linearity of the inner product to show it but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: It should be $z\in S$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y\in S$, then
$$
\|y-x\|^2=\|y-z+z-x\|^2=\|y-z\|^2+\|z-x\|^2-2\mathrm{Re}\langle y-z,x-z\rangle\geq \|x-z\|^2.
$$
Thus $d(x,S)=\|x-z\|$.